# Passing input to tidyverse summarize in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am having trouble calculating grouped summary stats for selected columns in a shiny app. It seems the base R summary functions for use in tidyverse summarize cannot recognize the string inputs from my shiny app. I'd like to have a table of min, max, mean, sd, and counts.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("summarycol", "Summary Stats For (Select One):", choices = c("mpg", "hp")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 table <- reactive({
   mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(mean = mean(input$summarycol))
 })
 output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(table())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get

```
Warning in mean.default(input$summarycol) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I also tried inserting `!!` before the input variable in mean but that gives

```
Warning in mean.default("mpg") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Is there a way to remove the quotes and have the base summary functions recognize the selected columns?

Comment: Use `summarize(mean = mean(!!sym(input$summarycol)))` You need to turn the input string into a proper symbol

Comment: Related: https://community.rstudio.com/t/unquoting-shiny-inputs-for-dplyr-functions/4281/4